Update a .NET Framework app to .NET Core. It's a VB.NET Windows service
I have a somewhat old .NET 4.7 Windows service written in VB.NET.
I would like to bring this up to .NET Core 8.0, but the upgrade wizard doesn't seem to want to deal with a lot of the work and I can't find anything really on if .NET Core supports a VB.NET Windows service....
I can find heaps of C# example of creating a console apps etc, but nothing for VB.NET, and when I create a new project, I only see a service project with C# language.
So before I give up, I figure I would at least ask... is what I am trying to do possible? Can I create a Windows service on .NET Core 8 with VB.NET ?
Are there any examples out there I can review to see how to do it?
As always.. Thanks!

If it can be done in C# then it can be done in VB. If you want more specific help, you'll need to ask about a specific problem. Note that many people, myself included, don't create Windows service projects in the first place, because they are a bit painful to debug. You can create a Console app project and run it as such in the debugger, then have it behave as a service for a Release build. Assuming the same types are part of .NET Core, you can do exactly the same thing in .NET 8 (note that the "Core" was dropped in .NET 5).

The following may be of interest: Introduction to Windows Service Applications (see the pink box)

Here is an example of a project that was created as a Console app but will run as a Windows service by default. The code is C# but the same principle works in VB:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DomainMapper.MapDomain();

    if (args.Length == 1 && args[0] == "/console")
    {
        // Run the application as a Console app.
        using (var processor = new ExportProcessor())
        {
            processor.RemoveObsoleteFiles();

            var folderPath = Config.GetSetting("ExportFolder");
            var folder = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
            var searchPattern = Config.GetSetting("ControlFileNamePattern");

            foreach (var file in folder.GetFiles(searchPattern).OrderBy(fi => fi.CreationTime))
            {
                processor.EnqueueFile(file.FullName);
            }

            processor.ProcessQueuedFiles();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Run the application as a Windows service.
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
                            {
                                new ExportService()
                            };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}

In the debugger, I use that "/console" switch to run it as a Console app for simpler debugging, but it runs as a Windows service without that. The crux here is that ServiceBase class, which your existing project presumably already uses. I have checked and that class does exist in .NET 8. It is in the System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController NuGet package.
The VB equivalent of that sort of code would look like this:
Module Program

    Sub Main(args As String())
        If args.FirstOrDefault() = "/console" Then
            'Do the do as a Console app.
        Else
            Dim services = New ServiceBase() {New SomeService}

            ServiceBase.Run(services)
        End If
    End Sub

End Module

What you do in the If block there would be basically the same as what you do in the service itself.
